# Determining Vo in a circuit with diodes

Tags: diodes

This is the question:
[image]

And this is my solution:

(a)

[image]

(b)

When `vI > 2.7`, D1 is on and D2 is off.
The circuit will look like:

[image]

`vo = vR2 + V1 + VDo`.
`VR2 = vI (R2/(R1+R2)) + 2.7 (R1/(R1+R2))`
=> `vo = vI (R2/(R1+R2)) + 2.7 (R1/(R1+R2)) + 2 + 0.7`.

When `vI < -4.7`, D1 is off and D2 is on.
The circuit will look like:

[image]

`Vo = - 4.7 V`

When `- 4.7 < vI < 2.7`, both diodes are off.
`vo = vI`

So,
`vo =`

- `vI (R2/(R1+R2)) + 2.7 (R1/(R1+R2)) + 2 + 0.7` ,  when `vI > 2.7 V`
- `- 4.7 V`  ,  when `vI < - 4.7 V`
- `vI`  ,  when `- 4.7 < vI < 2.7`

---

*Is this solution right or there are some mistakes?*

*Is there a better way to express `vo` when `vI > 2.7 V` ?*

Comment: when vI>2.7V then Vo=(vI+2.7)/2. (current through R1 must be the same as current throug R2, and take into account R1=R2 to express Vo in a better way).  For Vi<-4.7V and when - 4.7 < vI < 2.7 your values of Vo are correct.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

When Vi>2.7, your diagram is correct.

So ,Vo= (Voltage across the R2) + (Voltage drop across Diode = 0.7V)  + (Voltage from the DC                 source = 2V)

Use KVL to find the voltage across R2.

Since it is effectively a voltage divider with a voltage , Vi - 0.7 - 2 =Vi-2.7

So the Voltage across R2 is , VR2 = ( Vi-2.7) (R2/(R1+R2)

So, Vo= ( Vi-2.7) (R2/(R1+R2))  +  2.7

Since R1=R2, it can be solved to

Vo = (Vi+2.7)/2